# CS50 Readability Pset2

Tags: c, cs50

I am having trouble getting my code to correctly count the number of letters in a string my code still counts the spaces even tho the function I called below only checks for alphabetic characters it still counts the spaces. If I type Hello World is counts 11 letters even tho only 10 letters are present

isalpha()
checks for an alphabetic character; in the standard "C" locale, it is equivalent to (isupper(c) || islower(c)). In some locales, there may be additional characters for which isalpha() is true—letters which are neither uppercase nor lowercase.

Heres my code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <cs50.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //gets user input
    string input = get_string("Text: ");
    //counter for the number of letters
    int numLetters = 0;

    //looks at each character in the string
    for(int i = 0, n = strlen(input); i < n; i++)
    {
        //checks to see if the characeter is in the alphabet
        if(input[isalpha(i)])
        {
            //add to the number of letters in the string
            numLetters++;
        }


    }
    printf("letter(s) %i", numLetters);
    printf("\n");


}
```

Comment: What is this condition checking? if(input[isalpha(i)])

Comment: OT: regarding: `#include <math.h>`  Nothing in the header file: `math.h` is being used in the posted code.  It is a very poor programming practice to include header files those contents are not used

Answer (score 4):

The following if-statement in your loop:

```
if(input[isalpha(i)])
```

will use the result of `isalpha(i)` as an index into the `input` array, and evaluate its value.
Chances are, instead you would like to evaluate the result of the function `isalpha()` called with the ith character in the string, i.e.

```
if(isalpha(input[i]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Helped a lot I really do not know what I was thinking not doing it as a result of the function.

Answer (score 0):

The mistake is in your if statement, the one inside the loop. It should be:

```c
if (isalpha(input[i]) != 0)
{
  numLetters++;
}
```

I added the

```c
!= 0
```

part because 'isalpha' returns a positive integer if it is an alphabetical character, but returns zero if it's not. I hope you found this useful.

Comment: Welcome to SO. In C any condition value that is non-zero is treated as true. Therefore it is not required to explicitely compare `!=0`.

Comment: Yeah but for some reason  when I do  == 1 it doesn't work. So i just use  != 0

Comment: Comparing with `1` is different from comparing `!= 0`. For the condition there is absolutely no difference if `isalpha` return `1` or `17` or `-123`. All of them are true. But only 1 of them would match `==1`.

Comment: And you should never compare with 1 if you just want a trueish value. Either use `!=0` or skip the comparison completely as in the initial question. Both are identical

Comment: Thanks for telling me why == 1 didn't work while != 0 did. It explains a lot.